# Can you open a new shell with low priority in linux?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to open a new shell in a low priority (nice value = 19) so that every other command you type in the new shell has a low priority as well?

How?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way?

```
nice -n 19 sh
```

If you want a terminal window, something like

```
nice -n 19 xterm
```

might be more to your liking (unless you prefer `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, etc.).

Comment: nice -19 sh works but it's monochrome and upper arrow key and TAB don't work properly is there a way to fix that?

Comment: `bash` instead of `sh` if you want `bash` features.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake: `nice +19` results in `No such file or directory`, while `nice -19` works as expected.

Comment: @DragonLord: `csh` worked that way.  Technically we're both wrong anyway; POSIX killed both of those and it's `nice -n INCREMENT COMMAND ...`.